# filter for nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter in a search for a value in a specific column and then return all the values.

But when I do that I get undefined instead. it works fine when it is not a nested array.
This is the version that does not work.

```
data.filter(value =>{
        let A = console.log(value?.cells[3]?.value?.map((x)=> {{x?.status}}))
        //this returns undefined                                
        console.log(A)
        if(search =='')
        {
            return value;
        }
        else if
        (value?.cells[3]?.value?.map((x)=> {x?.status})?.toLowerCase().includes(search?.toLowerCase()))
        {
            
                return value;
            }
```

This is the schema of the json.

```
{
        "Name": "value",
        "results": [
            {
                "status": " status warning",
                "check": " check sometextwiththecheck",
                "results": " results sometextwiththeresultsofthecheck",
                "_id": ObjectId("62725d9cc52b45ba21a39193")
            },
            {
                "status": "2 status error",
                "check": "2 check sometextwiththecheck",
                "results": " 2 results sometextwiththeresultsofthecheck",
                "_id": ObjectId("62725d9cc52b45ba21a39193")
            }
        ]
}
```

and I am trying to filter by the array result with the key status.

This worked for me though

```
        data.?.filter(value =>{
        if(search =='')
        {
            return value;
        }
        else if
        (value?.cells[0]?.value?.toLowerCase().includes(search?.toLowerCase()))
        {
                return value;
        }
```

Comment: `console.log` always returns undefined, no matter what arguments you pass

Comment: Yes but it does not match my search value either. so the value is still incorrect

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const data = {
  Name: 'value',
  results: [
    {
      status: ' status warning',
      check: ' check sometextwiththecheck',
      results: ' results sometextwiththeresultsofthecheck',
      _id: '62725d9cc52b45ba21a39193',
    },
    {
      status: '2 status error',
      check: '2 check sometextwiththecheck',
      results: ' 2 results sometextwiththeresultsofthecheck',
      _id: '62725d9cc52b45ba21a39193',
    },
  ],
}

const search = 'err'

data.results = data.results.filter(({ status }) => status.includes(search))

console.log(data)
```